# Is there a python3 equivalent to the bash command `set -e`?

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, exception

Is there a python3 equivalent to to the bash command `set -e`? That is, to stop execution as soon as an error occurs? Or does python already do this?

Comment: An uncaught exception will, by default, propagate up the call stack and terminate the program, showing the exception message and traceback. It's not quite the same, since exceptions can be caught, but it's frankly a better setup than the extremely limited `bash` facilities.

Comment: I have to ask... have you tried writing a script and introducing an error and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python will always stop execution when an uncaught exception occurs.
It will print the traceback with information about the exception.